# How to fix this module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'lite'?

Tags: android, python, tensorflow

I copied the code from https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api
and while running the code it gives me this error module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'lite'

I haven't seen any tutorials that can fix my problem, so am trying to ask here if anyone can help me with my problem

This is the copied code from tensorflow lite official documentation and when I tried to run it, it gives me this error **"module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'lite'"**

```
import tensorflow as tf

img = tf.placeholder(name="img", dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1, 64, 64, 3))
var = tf.get_variable("weights", dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1, 64, 64, 3))
val = img + var
out = tf.identity(val, name="out")

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_session(sess, [img], [out])
  tflite_model = converter.convert()
  open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Comment: I've found a way to fix my own error by adding "contrib" to the converter. here is the code that worked for me and please notice contrib added to the code. 'converter = tf.contrib.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file("sample_android.h5")
tflite_model = converter.convert() '.

Comment: Using windows or macOS or Linux?

Comment: I fixed it using windows

Comment: How did you fix it? Can you give some info? I had similar problem, but could not solve.

Comment: Just add contrib to the code or download tf-nightly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the inconvenience, you can fix it by downloading the nightly.

Edit: or using tf.contrib.lite should also work.